# Textview in Fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am currently working on adding tabs into my activity. For the same, I am using the Google [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java).

My fragment xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTab" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My contents xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.musicisfun.allaboutfootball.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <com.example.musicisfun.allaboutfootball.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.example.musicisfun.allaboutfootball.tabs.SlidingTabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code looks like this:

```
 public static class TabFragment extends Fragment{

        public static TabFragment getInstance(int position){
            TabFragment tabFragment = new TabFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("site",position);
            tabFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return tabFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab,container,false);
            TextView textViewTab = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewTab);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle!=null){
                textViewTab.setText("Current Tab is" + bundle.getInt("site"));

            }
            return layout;
        }
    }
```

My fragment adaptor looks like this:

```
class TabPagerAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        String[] tab_names;
        public TabPagerAdaptor(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tab_names=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.feed_names);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabFragment tabFragment = TabFragment.getInstance(position);
            return tabFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return tab_names[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }


    }
```

and this is how i am invoking the tabs:

```
   mViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new TabPagerAdaptor(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

But when I run the code, I can't find the textview being shown even though two tabs are working fine.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are setting the ViewPager adapter ?

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot view your textView because the height of the ViewPager is `0dp` in your xml -

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />
```

you have to change that to  either `wrap_content` or `match_parent`-

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

     />
```

Also, Your LinearLayout's orientation is  `horizontal` and the width of `SlidingTabLayout` is `match_parent`.  `SlidingTabLayout` is occupying whole screen width leaving no room to display `Viewpager`.

**Your LinearLayout's orientation should be vertical not horizontal**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.example.musicisfun.allaboutfootball.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.example.musicisfun.allaboutfootball.tabs.SlidingTabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I made it horizontal as studio was giving an error when i was trying to set it up to vertical, but now its working great..cheers mate for your support